# SQL SELECT statement with a field's value from a value list

Tags: sql, select

I need to query a SQLite database for some entries containing a field the value of which can be one of a defined list: 'Token1', 'Token2', ..., 'TokenN' - potentially a long one.

The straightforward SELECT statement would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `token` = 'Token1' OR `token` = 'Token2' OR ...
```

- far from elegant. I wonder, is there a better way to formulate the statement?

Comment: Hint:  `IN` is more concise.

Comment: Why don't you use the wildcard character '%%' and avoid repeating the OR part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN` Clause

```
 SELECT * FROM `my_table`
 WHERE `token` in ('Token1','Token2', 'Token3', ....);
```

Comment: If this answer fits for you, please consider to mark it as answer so the community can benefit from it. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use the wildcard character `%%`.

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `token` like '%Token%'
```

Comment: I wrote an answer on your comment, but it somehow disappeared. (1) Thanks; (2) this is not quite what I mean: the tokens are not exactly 'Token1', 'Token2', etc., they are very different strings.

Answer (score 1):

If your defined list is or can be placed in a table, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM [employeeName] Where dept In (Select dept From #tbl)
```

Comment: I considered this option, but the strings, alas, are not in a table, but very external.